# Is "for to" + verb-base-form grammatical?

Tags: prepositions

We know that 'to' is often followed by verb-base-form, and 'for' by gerunds, eg;

1. It is for cleaning the sink.
2. I use it to clean the sink.

Source: [FOR-TO (purpose or reason)](https://www.learn-english-today.com/lessons/lesson_contents/grammar/for-to.html)

Is ['for to'](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20to%22&rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK819PK819&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_0Yb8vODfAhXC8uAKHZ0IBTEQpwUIHw&biw=1535&bih=794&dpr=1.25) also grammatically correct? (*Eg: It is used **for to** clean the sink.*)

A similar question asked on this platform is [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154396/as-for-to-in-comparison-to-as-for-or-as-to), however it's not well-answered either.

Comment: No. Infinitival clauses do not normally function as complements to prepositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "for to" in this way is no longer common. You may come across this in older books, historical quotes, etc., but most native speakers would not use the phrase in regular speech.

This [definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for_to) has the note "obsolete".